# Added many vertex to my object by mistake

Tags: modeling

Some time I add many vertex to my object by mistake, and I don't know how.

How I can escape from this operator?

[image]

Comment: You need to describe in the first place how those vertix got there, or it will be too many reason why they turn up.

Comment: what did you do by mistake that added the vertices?

Answer (score 2):

To remove unwanted vertices ... you can do the following.

1. Go to Edit Mode
2. Select Vertice Mode
3. Select the vertice or vertices you want to remove
4. Hit <kbd>X</kbd> key on the keyboard
5. Select "Dissolve Vertices"
6. Vertices will now be removed without destroying the face that it's attached to.

Enjoy.

[image]

Comment: This vertex add to al object .i cant delete by this way.i thought this add by some short cut

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that there are several vertices disconnected from other geometry and just floating in the space (this is what it looks like from your picture), then they could be unintentionally added in Edit mode for active mesh with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> clicking when nothing was selected.

To select them all quickly either:

- choose *Vertex* selection mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> menu, select one vertex not connected to anything and press <kbd>+Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Amount of connected edges*. As active vertex has 0 edges connected to it, all such vertices will be selected.
- in *Select* menu find *Select All By Trait* > *Non-Manifold* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. These vertices will be selected along with other non-manifold elements; to make only disconnected vertices become selected in operator's options uncheck everything but *Vertices*.
  Once selected, press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*.